# setting required on a json-schema array

Tags: json, jsonschema

I am trying to figure out how to set `required` on my json-schema array of objects. The `required` property works fine on an object just not an array.

Here is the items part of my json schema:

```
        "items": {
        "type": "array",
        "properties": {
            "item_id": {"type" : "number"},
            "quantity": {"type": "number"},
            "price": {"type" : "decimal"},
            "title": {"type": "string"},
            "description": {"type": "string"}
        },
        "required": ["item_id","quantity","price","title","description"],
        "additionalProperties" : false
    }
```

Here is the json array I am sending over. The json validation should fail since I am not passing a description in these items.

```
       "items": [
        {
            "item_id": 1,
            "quantity": 3,
            "price": 30,
            "title": "item1 new name"
        },
        {
            "item_id": 1,
            "quantity": 16,
            "price": 30,
            "title": "Test Two"
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I got it to work using [this validator](http://json-schema-validator.herokuapp.com/) by nesting the part of the schema for the array elements inside a object with the name `items`. The schema now has two nested `items` fields, but that is because one is a keyword in JSONSchema and the other because your JSON actually has a field called `items`

JSONSchema:

```
{
   "type":"object",
   "properties":{
      "items":{
         "type":"array",
         "items":{
            "properties":{
               "item_id":{
                  "type":"number"
               },
               "quantity":{
                  "type":"number"
               },
               "price":{
                  "type":"number"
               },
               "title":{
                  "type":"string"
               },
               "description":{
                  "type":"string"
               }
            },
            "required":[
               "item_id",
               "quantity",
               "price",
               "title",
               "description"
            ],
            "additionalProperties":false
         }
      }
   }
}
```

JSON:

```
{
   "items":[
      {
         "item_id":1,
         "quantity":3,
         "price":30,
         "title":"item1 new name"
      },
      {
         "item_id":1,
         "quantity":16,
         "price":30,
         "title":"Test Two"
      }
   ]
}
```

Output with two errors about missing description fields:

```
[ {
  "level" : "error",
  "schema" : {
    "loadingURI" : "#",
    "pointer" : "/properties/items/items"
  },
  "instance" : {
    "pointer" : "/items/0"
  },
  "domain" : "validation",
  "keyword" : "required",
  "message" : "missing required property(ies)",
  "required" : [ "description", "item_id", "price", "quantity", "title" ],
  "missing" : [ "description" ]
}, {
  "level" : "error",
  "schema" : {
    "loadingURI" : "#",
    "pointer" : "/properties/items/items"
  },
  "instance" : {
    "pointer" : "/items/1"
  },
  "domain" : "validation",
  "keyword" : "required",
  "message" : "missing required property(ies)",
  "required" : [ "description", "item_id", "price", "quantity", "title" ],
  "missing" : [ "description" ]
} ]
```

Try pasting the above into [here](http://json-schema-validator.herokuapp.com/) to see the same output generated.

Comment: Above solution doesn't return schema error for empty array

Answer (score 10):

I realize this is an old thread, but since this question is linked from jsonschema.net, I thought it might be worth chiming in...

The problem with your original example is that you're declaring "properties" for an "array" type, rather than declaring "items" for the array, and then declaring an "object" type (with "properties") that populates the array. Here's a revised version of the original schema snippet:

```
"items": {
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "item_id": {"type" : "number"},
            "quantity": {"type": "number"},
            "price": {"type" : "decimal"},
            "title": {"type": "string"},
            "description": {"type": "string"}
        },
        "required": ["item_id","quantity","price","title","description"],
        "additionalProperties" : false
    }
}
```

I would recommend against using the term "items" for the name of the array, to avoid confusion, but there's nothing stopping you from doing that...

Answer (score 8):

Maybe your validator only supports JSONSchema v3?

The way `required` works changed between v3 and v4:

- In v3 `required` is a boolean: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-zyp-json-schema-03#section-5.7
- In v4 `required` is an array of strings (like in your example): https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-fge-json-schema-validation-00#section-5.4.3

Comment: json-schema.org appears to be using v4.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, for me it worked like this:

```py
schema = {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "price": {"type": "number"},
        "name": {"type": "string", 'required': True}, # set require = True
        "details": {"type": "object"},
    }
}
```